# Show "page not found" when user requests index.php/blahblahblah

Tags: php, apache

I have the following files in apache server:

```
pageNotFound.php
index.php
style.css
login.php
```

I have edited httpd.conf so if user types an address like localhost/wrongpage.php apache shows  localhost/pageNotFound.php. My problem is that when a user types localhost/index.php/blablaitypewhateveriwant or even localhost/index.php/, page index.php comes up with an awful appearence (no css or javascript enabled). So i want to restrict access cases like these and show pageNotFound.php

edit: To make things easier visit those links to see the difference:http://www.developphp.com/donate.php, http://www.developphp.com/donate.php/blahblah

Comment: post your httpd.conf and/or .htaccess. We really can't guess what you've put in those files.

Comment: I changed only one line in  httpd.conf from #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html to ErrorDocument 404 /pageNotFound.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your edit. You requested page is not a 404. But in your developer tool you can read :

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.developphp.com/donate.php/style/layout_001.css".`[...]

You can solve this problem by changing all your css/javascript include by adding slashes. For instance :

`style/layout_001.css` to `/style/layout_001.css`

Comment: Something like that was going wrong im my code, too. Is it worth anyway to create a way to programatically block/redirect users when typing addresses like  localhost/index.php/itypewhateveriwant

Comment: You can have a look for UrlRewriting with .htacess to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify **.htaccess**

```
ERRORDOCUMENT 404 /pageNotFound.php
```

Comment: Yes i've already done that but redirects me only when i type something like localhost/wrongpage.php and no localhost/index.php/blablaitypewhateveriwant